# How to create release excluding certain files in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

In my git project, the **master** and **dev** branches are both at the same commit. They include a number of translation/layout files that I am currently working on, but are not completed. I need to build a new release of the project which excludes these files, but will almost certainly require some additional changes to other files.

If I create a new branch **rel**, delete the relevant files from **rel** branch and work towards a releasable version, what is the best way of then merging the changes from rel back into dev without git deleting these files from **dev**? Is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

e.g. before merge

```
dev
  - code1
  - code2
  - trans1
  - trans2
  - layout1
  - layout2

rel
  - code1
  - code2 (modified)
  - trans1 (modified)
  - layout1 (modified)
```

after merge

```
dev
  - code1
  - code2 (modified)
  - trans1 (modified)
  - trans2
  - layout1 (modified)
  - layout2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear whether the changes you need to make are related to the presence or lack of the those files you intend to remove and if they will work with the removed files when they are back. Here's an approach you use to achieve what you want.

Create two branches, `rel-modified` and `rel-removed`. Make changes and commit them to the fist. Remove files and commit them to the second. Create a branch `rel` and merge to first two into it. You can deploy `rel`.

Then merge only `rel-modified` back to `dev` to reflect the changes and keep the removed files.

Comment: The files that I need to remove are uncompleted language translations and layouts that relate to those languages. The changes that I will need to make are any bug fixes or adjustments to the code needed for a release which may arise from removing the incomplete translations, but will probably mostly be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a habit to keep the modifications in one commit and removing whatever files should not be part of the release in a separate commit on top of the modifications. This is a non-issue then since you would only merge back the modifications.